# Getting Error on Building APK - Android Studio

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I am a newbie and trying to build an APK in android studio. Getting the following error

```
Error : Android Resource Packaging:[Project Name] D:\react-app\Android\App
Error : Android Resource Packaging:[Project Name] src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:45: error:Error:no resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/App_name).
```

There are approx 9 errors showing.
Please help to resolve the problem.

Comment: post your manifest and string here

Comment: @Vikas Rai, check that strings.xml file contains App_name variable or not by default it is app_name (follow folder structure Android => app => res => values => strings.xml)

Comment: string.XML
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Becrux-Grocery</string>
<string name="facebook_app_id">1401655059993888</string>
<!-- <string name="facebook_app_id">206572796668097</string> -->
<string name="fb_login_protocol_scheme">1401655059993888</string>
</resources>

Comment: Manifest.xml error showing in below
<application
      android:name="com.rnbecruxBoy.MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

<activity
        android:name="com.rnbecruxBoy.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"

Answer (score 1):

The possible answer to your mentioned error is make sure
**string.xml** file under

> android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml

should look like this

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">YOUR_APP_NAME</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: it is as below<resources>
<string name="app_name">Becrux-Grocery</string>
<string name="facebook_app_id">1401655059993888</string>
<!-- <string name="facebook_app_id">206572796668097</string> -->
<string name="fb_login_protocol_scheme">1401655059993888</string>
</resources>